# Getting error when trying to use starttls() in PySpark application in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: pyspark, smtp, azure-synapse

I've got a two part question.  I've been asked to have an email sent whenever an error occurs when running a Notebook in Azure Synapse.  The Notebook is going to be run in a pipeline, so I asked them why they didn't just have the email sent from the pipeline, since they know how to do it from there.  They gave me a long answer which I didn't understand, so I guess it has to be done inside Synapse.

So anyway, do you have any suggestions as to how to do this?  I thought of maybe doing a Logic App or Function and having the Logic App or Function called via the PySpark application.

Another way I am trying and do it is inside the PySpark application itself.  Anyway I have the following code:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", port=587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
```

So anyway, when it gets to smtp.starttls(), I get an error message

> SMTPNotSupportedError:  STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

I only get this error when trying to do it in PySpark in Synapse. When I do it in Python in Visual Studio on my other machine and run it there, I don't get the error, and I can send the email.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks.